# R shiny collapse long rows in data table

Tags: r, datatable, shiny

I have a data table with a lot of text in some rows.

What I would like to do is to limit the default display of text in the row to 4 lines and then when the row is clicked to either expand it, or only display that specific row.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

data <- data.frame(
  question = c("question1", "question2", "guestion3", paste0("A ", paste0(rep("very", 1000), collapse = " "), "long question"), "..."),
  answer = c("answer1", "answer2", paste0("A ", paste0(rep("very", 1000), collapse = " "), "long answer"),
             paste0("Another ", paste0(rep("very", 200), collapse = " "), "long answer"), "...")
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput(('DTOut'))
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$DTOut <- DT::renderDataTable({
    data
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I was trying to play with max-height and toggle, however wasn't very successful there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution from the [DT](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/options.html) page. But it uses the number of characters and the remaining text it shows when hovering over the cell.

```
datatable(data, options = list(columnDefs = list(list(
  targets = c(1,2),
  render = JS(
   "function(data, type, row, meta) {",
   "return type === 'display' && data.length > 100 ?",
   "'<span title=\"' + data + '\">' + data.substr(0, 100) + '...</span>' : data;",
   "}")
))))
```

Comment: This breaks when there are NAs in the desired column. Try `dt[is.na(dt)] <- ""` before using

Comment: apparently the code in `options` is run before the code in `data`, which has important ramifications in Shiny (if you are using a reactive variable to define "targets"), or anywhere where order may matter

Comment: @hedgedandlevered if you have a new implementation/scenario  then please ask a new question amd linked to this question if its help.

Comment: I'm just commenting on some more specific implementations of this problem; corner cases that may result in unintended behavior I found. People using shiny are likely to use this function, so just helping where I ran into an issue. If you want to make a new question, I'll answer that.